# How do I get Anjuta to higlight errors/lines produced by my build system (waf)?

Tags: c++, ide, waf, anjuta

Waf outputs errors like the following

```
Waf: Entering directory `/home/atomos/dc_mmo/netclient/build'
[47/53] c: c_lib/c_lib.c -> build/c_lib/c_lib.c.1.o
In file included from ../c_lib/c_lib.c:12:
../c_lib/./physics/common.c: In function ‘rk4_accelerate’:
../c_lib/./physics/common.c:301: warning: unused variable ‘spring’
In file included from ../c_lib/c_lib.c:15:
../c_lib/./objects/grenade.c: In function ‘grenade_draw’:
../c_lib/./objects/grenade.c:91: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../c_lib/./objects/grenade.c:91: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../c_lib/./objects/grenade.c:91: error: for each function it appears in.)
In file included from ../c_lib/c_lib.c:16:
../c_lib/./objects/neutron.c: In function ‘neutron_draw’:
../c_lib/./objects/neutron.c:191: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from ../c_lib/./agent/agent_include.h:21,
                 from ../c_lib/c_lib.c:23:
../c_lib/./agent/./agent_client.c: In function ‘set_agent_control_state’:
../c_lib/./agent/./agent_client.c:58: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

How can i get Anjuta to show errors at bottom and allow me to jump to error by clicking on it?

How can I configure Anjuta to run my build system on compile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that eclipse looks for make: in the error code (this should be configurable) So you have to patch eclipse or waf so they agree on the format of the error message.

There was a patch to waf in [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/waf/issues/detail?id=366&can=1&q=eclipse)